# Can not load config my module in order detail

Tags: php, magento, module, magento-1.4

I have development magento version 1.4.1.0 module payment, because my client use it.

After I done create it, I test in form checkout it show and everything is working when use payment.

In user order detail, is correctly show my title module. When I go to `Sales` > `Order`, it show the order list. But I click one of the order to order details, it goes error. The error said:

> Cannot load configuration for payment method "reddotpayment"

```
Trace:
#0 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Helper\Data.php(48): Mage::throwException('Cannot load con...')
#1 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Helper\Data.php(209): Mage_Payment_Helper_Data->getMethodInstance('reddotpayment')
#2 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Transactions\Grid.php(104): Mage_Payment_Helper_Data->getPaymentMethodList(true)
#3 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(574): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Transactions_Grid->_prepareColumns()
#4 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(582): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#5 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(752): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#6 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Tabs.php(289): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Transactions))
#8 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(212): include('C:\Users\hendra...')
#9 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(239): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#10 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(253): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#11 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(753): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(753): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#15 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(520): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(471): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#17 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#18 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(212): include('C:\Users\hendra...')
#19 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(239): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#20 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(253): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(753): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(389): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\OrderController.php(119): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
#27 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#28 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\app\Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 C:\Users\hendrathings\Documents\Development\magento1410\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}
```

Please help me.
what can I do for fix this error?

Comment: Can you show your config.xml content?

Comment: @Sohel Rana, thanks for reply. here the config xml: [link](http://pastebin.com/L2GHVpdY). Maybe its problem in `model` to show detail config, but I dont know.